# python try-except, exception handling

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I have 10 links in a list, upon clicked,which will open a new window. Different links would yield different set of pages, however i have 3 common elements for all 10 links.

Following is the function example.

```
def handle_window(self):
    self.driver.go_to_new_window()

    try: # block 1
        elements = ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
        for element in elements:

            try:  #block 2
                self.assertEqual(True, is_exist_in_new_window(element)))
            except:
                continue

    except:
        # in 'try block 2' if assert yields true at least once,
        print 'passed'
        # if it fails for all 3 elements,
        print 'failed'
    self.driver.close_current_window()
    self.driver.go_to_main_window()
```

I am not sure how do i evaluate the results of 'try block 2', so that to do some action in block 1. 
Any possible solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `"element1"`, etc. are meant to be CSS selectors, the most efficient way would be:

```
elements = ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
self.assertTrue(exists_in_new_window(",".join(elements)))
```

(I've renamed `is_exist_in_new_window` to `exists_in_new_window`.) The `,` operator in CSS means "or". So the CSS selector passed to `exists_in_new_window` means you are looking for "element1" or "element2" or "element3". Doing it this way will need one round-trip between the Selenium client and the browser, no matter what. Note that the code above is not meant to handle meaningfully the case where `elements` is a zero-length list.

With XPath selectors you could use the `|` operator to perform a similar transformation. In this case, I would want to additionally use parentheses to preserve semantics of the individual selectors so something like `"(" + ")|(".join(elements) + ")"`. (I believe the semantics issue does not arise in CSS due to CSS' very rigid syntax.)

In the more general case where it is not possible to combine the search criteria into one expression, one can fall back onto alecxe's suggestion:

```
elements = ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
self.assertTrue(any((exists_in_new_window(element) for element in elements)))
```

This method causes a minimum of `min(1, len(elements))` round-trips between the Selenium client and the browser and a maximum of `len(elements)` depending on what is present on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [any()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check if at least one element existed on a page:

```
elements = ["element1", "element2", "element3"]
value = any((is_exist_in_new_window(element) for element in elements))
self.assertTrue(value)
```

This code assumes `is_exist_in_new_window()` returns `True` or `False`.

Hope that helps.